# Как прописать чтобы $PATH не сбрасывался при входе в Терминал?

Tags: консоль, macos

ksbykov@MacBook-Pro-Kirill ~ % mysql

zsh: command not found: mysql

ksbykov@MacBook-Pro-Kirill ~ % echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

ksbykov@MacBook-Pro-Kirill ~ % export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH

ksbykov@MacBook-Pro-Kirill ~ % mysql

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 9
Server version: 8.0.19 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>

---

При перезапуске терминала приходиться снова вводить экспорт, чтобы запустить mysql. Как вылечить, куда прописать?

В .bash_profile добавил, но он также не читается автоматом при запуске терминала, только через SOURCE :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте ваши экспорты переменных в `~/.bashrc`(для bash) и в `~/.zshrc` для zsh.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо большое!

Comment: @КириллБыков Всегда пожалуйста. Обращайтесь! :-)